# URLRewrite IIS 7

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am trying to perform a simple URLRewriting. if you visit azamsharp.com it will take to some folder browsing structure it should go to http://www.azamsharp.com/AzamSharpWebApps/Default.aspx.

I don't want to see the AzamSharpWebApps in the URL: Here is the URL Rewrite I am using:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Virtual Director" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{MyDomains:{HTTP_HOST}}" pattern="(.+)" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}{REQUEST_URI}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
      <rewriteMaps>
        <rewriteMap name="MyDomains">
          <add key="azamsharp.com" value="/AzamSharpWebApps/default.aspx" />
          <add key="www.azamsharp.com" value="/AzamSharpWebApps/default.aspx" />
        </rewriteMap>
      </rewriteMaps>
    </rewrite>

  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how IIS UrlRewrite works, but at a general regex level you want to replace `^(?!/AzamSharpWebApps).+` with `/AzamSharpWebApps/$0`

The `^` is start of string, and the `(?!`..`)` is a negative lookahead, saying "make sure the following text is not "/AzamSharpWebApps", and then the .+ matches any character until the end of the string.

In the replace side, the `$0` indicates the entire captured text - so basically the regex is saying "if it doesn't already start with "/AzamSharpWebApps", prefix it with that.

(You'll need to experiment with whether you need a / before the $0 or not.)

Anyhow, looks like IIS uses `{C:0}` instead of `$0`, just to be different, so I guess it will look something like this inside the rule:

```
<match url="^(?!/AzamSharpWebApps).+" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="/AzamSharpWebApps{C:0}" />
```

But possibly it needs more than just that.